# How to know endianness of a file in a Hex Editor

Tags: hex, byte, offset, endianness

I've opened a file in the free hex editor program "HxD", **how to know the endianness of a file in hex editor ? I would like to know the way,** i can't know whether it's big endian or little endian, any help would be very appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the editor to byte group and then the byte at the lowest address in a word will be LSB. for example in HxD we can set the byte group size to 1